# Microsoft single tenant authentication with Firebase

Tags: javascript, azure, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

For a work-related app I use Firebase authentication with Microsoft. In this case, however, it is important that only people from my company (we use Office 365) can sign into this application. I have everything set-up and working in a non-firebase context. But when I use Firebase for authentication, it seems to always point to the `/common/` endpoint. This causes problem with my single-tenant-application. If I set the application to accept all tenants, the app works again. But obviously, now everyone can log into my application.

[image: The problem]

The pop-up is called with a rather conventional:

```
  const provider = new auth.OAuthProvider("microsoft.com");
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    tenant: "[tenantName].com"
  });

  auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(result => {
```

But I can't find any instructions on changing the oauth endpoint to use the single tenant endpoint.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the above is not exactly true. I've switched to signing in with a redirect, and now it (mysteriously) works.

```
  const provider = new auth.OAuthProvider("microsoft.com");
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    tenant: "[tenant].com"
  });


  auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

I have tested this. The tenant is named in the redirect, and people from other tenants cannot log in.

Answer (score 3):

> But I can't find any instructions on changing the oauth endpoint to
>   use the single tenant endpoint.

We can not change the oauth endpoint, even though we add the tenant information to customParameters. The endpoint always use common as the value of tenant. This is the default design.

If we enable Microsoft as a sign-in provider, users using Microsoft accounts (Azure Active Directory and personal Microsoft accounts) can sign in.

Comment: I read here that Firebase is not capable of doing an application like this? That's unfortunate. I'll see if I can find an alternative approach and if I find the same conclusion, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @VicV Yes, I raised a support ticket to firebase support team. Here is their reply for your reference. "Upon checking with the team, it seems that your case is a feature request from our end. There is already an internal request filed to add tenant support for Microsoft.

For now, I suggest that you keep an eye out for updates on our official blog and release notes for newly added products, features, and SDKs."